# Connection abort during data transformation with CloverDX

Tags: java, cloveretl

I'm working on data transformations using CloverDX. When I run my graph, on my 5th `SpreadsheetDataWriter` component, it stops with the below error. Does anyone know how to debug the below error? This kinda works on my laptop(it only stops halfway since my laptop only has 8gb of RAM), but here on my desktop I have 16GB RAM w/c I believe is fairly sufficient for clover

```
20:33:25,082 INFO : === CloverDX 5.5.0.21 Starting ===
20:33:31,841 INFO : === CloverDX Runtime 5.5.0.21 Started @6 sec ===
20:33:31,847 INFO : Available memory:
 Heap memory (initial/used/max): 128 MB/133 MB/14.2 GB
 Non-heap memory (initial/used): 2 MB/125 MB
Dec 27, 2019 8:37:33 PM com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate doGet
SEVERE: caught throwable
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: null
    at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.MtomCodec.encode(MtomCodec.java:206)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.SOAPBindingCodec.encode(SOAPBindingCodec.java:242)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.encodePacket(HttpAdapter.java:636)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.access$100(HttpAdapter.java:108)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:878)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:422)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.invokeAsync(ServletAdapter.java:225)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.doGet(WSServletDelegate.java:161)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.doPost(WSServletDelegate.java:197)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet.doPost(WSServlet.java:81)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder$NotAsyncServlet.service(ServletHolder.java:1401)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1617)
    at com.cloveretl.server.filter.GzipInputFilter.doFilter(Main:143)
    at com.cloveretl.server.worker.commons.filter.HttpFilterBase.doFilter(Main:41)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604)
    at com.cloveretl.server.filter.GzipOutputFilter.doFilter(Main:764)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604)
    at com.cloveretl.server.filter.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(Main:61)
    at com.cloveretl.server.worker.commons.filter.HttpFilterBase.doFilter(Main:41)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604)
    at com.cloveretl.server.filter.InitCheckFilter.doFilter(Main:54)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604)
    at com.cloveretl.server.filter.ReverseProxyFilter.doFilter(Main:77)
    at com.cloveretl.server.worker.commons.filter.HttpFilterBase.doFilter(Main:41)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604)
    at com.cloveretl.server.filter.ClientTrackingFilter.doFilter(Main:47)
    at com.cloveretl.server.worker.commons.filter.HttpFilterBase.doFilter(Main:41)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1596)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:545)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:536)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1592)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1296)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:485)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1562)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1211)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:500)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:386)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:562)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:378)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:270)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:806)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:938)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: null
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter._finishDocument(BaseStreamWriter.java:1473)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.writeEndDocument(BaseStreamWriter.java:550)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.util.xml.XMLStreamWriterFilter.writeEndDocument(XMLStreamWriterFilter.java:75)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.util.xml.XMLStreamWriterFilter.writeEndDocument(XMLStreamWriterFilter.java:75)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.message.AbstractMessageImpl.writeTo(AbstractMessageImpl.java:196)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.message.MessageWrapper.writeTo(MessageWrapper.java:226)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.MtomCodec.encode(MtomCodec.java:188)
    ... 65 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint.flush(ChannelEndPoint.java:283)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher.flush(WriteFlusher.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher.write(WriteFlusher.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractEndPoint.write(AbstractEndPoint.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$SendCallback.process(HttpConnection.java:810)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.IteratingCallback.processing(IteratingCallback.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.IteratingCallback.iterate(IteratingCallback.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.send(HttpConnection.java:541)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.sendResponse(HttpChannel.java:844)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.write(HttpChannel.java:916)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:259)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.flush(HttpOutput.java:506)
    at java.io.FilterOutputStream.flush(FilterOutputStream.java:140)
    at com.ctc.wstx.io.UTF8Writer.flush(UTF8Writer.java:103)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BufferingXmlWriter.flush(BufferingXmlWriter.java:242)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BufferingXmlWriter.close(BufferingXmlWriter.java:215)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter._finishDocument(BaseStreamWriter.java:1471)
    ... 71 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.writev0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.writev(SocketDispatcher.java:55)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:148)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:504)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint.flush(ChannelEndPoint.java:263)
    ... 88 more

Dec 27, 2019 8:37:33 PM com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate doGet
SEVERE: caught throwable
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: null
    at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.MtomCodec.encode(MtomCodec.java:206)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.SOAPBindingCodec.encode(SOAPBindingCodec.java:242)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.encodePacket(HttpAdapter.java:636)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.access$100(HttpAdapter.java:108)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:878)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:422)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.invokeAsync(ServletAdapter.java:225)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.doGet(WSServletDelegate.java:161)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.doPost(WSServletDelegate.java:197)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet.doPost(WSServlet.java:81)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder$NotAsyncServlet.service(ServletHolder.java:1401)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1617)
    at com.cloveretl.server.filter.GzipInputFilter.doFilter(Main:143)
    at com.cloveretl.server.worker.commons.filter.HttpFilterBase.doFilter(Main:41)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604)
    at com.cloveretl.server.filter.GzipOutputFilter.doFilter(Main:764)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604)
    at com.cloveretl.server.filter.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(Main:61)
    at com.cloveretl.server.worker.commons.filter.HttpFilterBase.doFilter(Main:41)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604)
    at com.cloveretl.server.filter.InitCheckFilter.doFilter(Main:54)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604)
    at com.cloveretl.server.filter.ReverseProxyFilter.doFilter(Main:77)
    at com.cloveretl.server.worker.commons.filter.HttpFilterBase.doFilter(Main:41)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604)
    at com.cloveretl.server.filter.ClientTrackingFilter.doFilter(Main:47)
    at com.cloveretl.server.worker.commons.filter.HttpFilterBase.doFilter(Main:41)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1596)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:545)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:536)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1592)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1296)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:485)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1562)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1211)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:500)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:386)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:562)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:378)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:270)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:806)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:938)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: null
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter._finishDocument(BaseStreamWriter.java:1473)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.writeEndDocument(BaseStreamWriter.java:550)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.util.xml.XMLStreamWriterFilter.writeEndDocument(XMLStreamWriterFilter.java:75)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.util.xml.XMLStreamWriterFilter.writeEndDocument(XMLStreamWriterFilter.java:75)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.message.AbstractMessageImpl.writeTo(AbstractMessageImpl.java:196)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.message.MessageWrapper.writeTo(MessageWrapper.java:226)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.MtomCodec.encode(MtomCodec.java:188)
    ... 65 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint.flush(ChannelEndPoint.java:283)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher.flush(WriteFlusher.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher.write(WriteFlusher.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractEndPoint.write(AbstractEndPoint.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$SendCallback.process(HttpConnection.java:810)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.IteratingCallback.processing(IteratingCallback.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.IteratingCallback.iterate(IteratingCallback.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.send(HttpConnection.java:541)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.sendResponse(HttpChannel.java:844)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.write(HttpChannel.java:916)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:259)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.flush(HttpOutput.java:506)
    at java.io.FilterOutputStream.flush(FilterOutputStream.java:140)
    at com.ctc.wstx.io.UTF8Writer.flush(UTF8Writer.java:103)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BufferingXmlWriter.flush(BufferingXmlWriter.java:242)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BufferingXmlWriter.close(BufferingXmlWriter.java:215)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter._finishDocument(BaseStreamWriter.java:1471)
    ... 71 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.writev0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.writev(SocketDispatcher.java:55)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:148)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:504)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint.flush(ChannelEndPoint.java:263)
    ... 88 more

Dec 27, 2019 8:37:33 PM com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate doGet
SEVERE: caught throwable
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: null
    at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.MtomCodec.encode(MtomCodec.java:206)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.SOAPBindingCodec.encode(SOAPBindingCodec.java:242)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.encodePacket(HttpAdapter.java:636)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.access$100(HttpAdapter.java:108)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:878)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:422)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.invokeAsync(ServletAdapter.java:225)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.doGet(WSServletDelegate.java:161)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.doPost(WSServletDelegate.java:197)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet.doPost(WSServlet.java:81)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder$NotAsyncServlet.service(ServletHolder.java:1401)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1617)
    at com.cloveretl.server.filter.GzipInputFilter.doFilter(Main:143)
    at com.cloveretl.server.worker.commons.filter.HttpFilterBase.doFilter(Main:41)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604)
    at com.cloveretl.server.filter.GzipOutputFilter.doFilter(Main:764)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604)
    at com.cloveretl.server.filter.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(Main:61)
    at com.cloveretl.server.worker.commons.filter.HttpFilterBase.doFilter(Main:41)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604)
    at com.cloveretl.server.filter.InitCheckFilter.doFilter(Main:54)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604)
    at com.cloveretl.server.filter.ReverseProxyFilter.doFilter(Main:77)
    at com.cloveretl.server.worker.commons.filter.HttpFilterBase.doFilter(Main:41)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604)
    at com.cloveretl.server.filter.ClientTrackingFilter.doFilter(Main:47)
    at com.cloveretl.server.worker.commons.filter.HttpFilterBase.doFilter(Main:41)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1596)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:545)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:536)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1592)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1296)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:485)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1562)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1211)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:500)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:386)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:562)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:378)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:270)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:806)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:938)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: null
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter._finishDocument(BaseStreamWriter.java:1473)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.writeEndDocument(BaseStreamWriter.java:550)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.util.xml.XMLStreamWriterFilter.writeEndDocument(XMLStreamWriterFilter.java:75)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.util.xml.XMLStreamWriterFilter.writeEndDocument(XMLStreamWriterFilter.java:75)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.message.AbstractMessageImpl.writeTo(AbstractMessageImpl.java:196)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.message.MessageWrapper.writeTo(MessageWrapper.java:226)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.MtomCodec.encode(MtomCodec.java:188)
    ... 65 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint.flush(ChannelEndPoint.java:283)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher.flush(WriteFlusher.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher.write(WriteFlusher.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractEndPoint.write(AbstractEndPoint.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$SendCallback.process(HttpConnection.java:810)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.IteratingCallback.processing(IteratingCallback.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.IteratingCallback.iterate(IteratingCallback.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.send(HttpConnection.java:541)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.sendResponse(HttpChannel.java:844)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.write(HttpChannel.java:916)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:259)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.flush(HttpOutput.java:506)
    at java.io.FilterOutputStream.flush(FilterOutputStream.java:140)
    at com.ctc.wstx.io.UTF8Writer.flush(UTF8Writer.java:103)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BufferingXmlWriter.flush(BufferingXmlWriter.java:242)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BufferingXmlWriter.close(BufferingXmlWriter.java:215)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter._finishDocument(BaseStreamWriter.java:1471)
    ... 71 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.writev0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.writev(SocketDispatcher.java:55)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:148)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:504)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint.flush(ChannelEndPoint.java:263)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for posing your question. My name is George and I'm one of the Software Support Engineers at CloverDX. To better assist you, please see below to the list of questions. Looking forward to hearing from you.

1.) You mention "This kinda works on my laptop(it only stops halfway since my laptop only has 8gb of RAM), but here on my desktop I have 16GB RAM w/c I believe is fairly sufficient for clover". Do you encounter the error on the 5th SpreadsheetDataWriter component on both machines (laptop with 8gb of RAM and desktop with 16GB of RAM)? If not, then at which point (if any) during the graph run do you encounter the error when running it on both machines?

2.) Do you encounter the error when running other graphs in CloverDX Designer or is it specifically the one you attached in your initial response?

3.) If possible and as a test, can you temporarily disable your firewall, close down Designer, restart it, and try running the graph again? The most likely cause of this type of error is the firewall, so to completely rule this out as a possibility, I'd like you to give this a try.

Best,

George